# Django: Mostrar relatório ganhos e despesas de um sistema de gestão em django

Tags: python, django

Eu tenho um sistema de gestão em django e gostaria de salvar em um lugar o relatório de todas as ganhos(Pago=True), inadimplências (pago=False) e despesas do mês ou período no próprio django admin, em um template ou em um documento PDF.

```
class MovDiario(models.Model):
    cliente = models.ForeignKey('Cliente', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    veiculo = models.ForeignKey('Veiculo', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    placa = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    servico = models.ManyToManyField('Servico')
    valor = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    pagamento = models.ForeignKey('FormPagamento', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    pago = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    entregue = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Quero saber principalmente como posso acessar a soma de todos os valores pagos para fazer um balanço financeiro

Comment: O melhor jeito de você conseguir ajuda no site é colocando o código do que já fez e onde está com dificuldade. Confira na Central de Ajuda como fazer uma boa pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá viva uma forma de obteres a soma, é assim:

Em Python 2:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
total = MovDiario.objects.filter(pago=True).aggregate(Sum('valor')).values()[0]
```

Em Python 3:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
valor_pago = list(MovDiario.objects.filter(pago=True).aggregate(Sum('valor')).values())[0]
```

Comment: Não entendi bem onde eu deveria colocar esta parte do código, você gostaria de ver o código completo?

Comment: Tens uma função save() algures para atualizar o teu MovDiario():, certo? Não tenho acesso ao teu código, se quiseres partilha um repositório coloca publico se não tiveres nada que não possa ser partilhado. Podes sempre criar um novo modelo (tabela), com AgregadoMovimentos, assim agregas todos os clientes com total do pagamento pago, pendente e entregue, mas simplificando. No admin podes adicionar um package https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/3.0/howto/outputting-pdf/, aqui vais criar uma função que carrega valores para o PDF e aqui sim utilizas o código que partilhei.

Comment: Outro bom exemplo de tutorial para criar PDF no django Admin...https://medium.com/code-rocket-blog/gerando-pdf-a-partir-de-html-no-admin-do-django-6f7c3528f5b3